# How to force ORM lite to generate right DELETE query?

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

I have the following issue when using orm lite in android project:

I have rows that should be removed from the table. Always all rows of table. So the query can always be like: "DELETE ALL FROM ..."

I am deleting the rows by this code:

```
Logger.getDataAccessLogger()
                    .info("clearLocationsPendingToSend...");
            final Dao<LocationDto, Integer> pendingLocationsDao = DBConnectionFactory
                    .getInstance(mCtx).getPendingLocationsDao();

            pendingLocationsDao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    pendingLocationsDao.delete(pendingLocationsDao
                            .queryForAll());
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

The problem is that this approach is generating sql query like this:

```
DELETE FROM `pendingLocations` WHERE `id` IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?.........
```

So, when there is a lot of rows, like 5000, then i get exception of too many parameters in sql:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: too many SQL variables (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM `pendingLocations` WHERE `id` IN (?,?,?,.....
```

How should i change the code to force orm to don't use such query? To use DELETE all instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

try this code to delete all data from `pendingLocations` table where DatabaseTable class is LocationDto.

```
try {
       Dao<LocationDto, Integer> pendingLocationsDao = dbHelper.getPendingLocationsDao();
        DeleteBuilder<LocationDto, Integer> deleteBuilder = pendingLocationsDao .deleteBuilder();
        deleteBuilder.delete();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```